# Finding most popular and most unique records using SQL

Tags: sql, ms-access

My mom wanted a baby name game for my brother's baby shower. Wanting to learn python, I volunteered to do it. I pretty much have the python bit, it's the SQL that is throwing me.

The way the game is supposed to work is everyone at the shower writes down names on paper, I manually enter them into Excel (normalizing spellings as much as possible) and export to MS Access. Then I run my python program to find the player with the most popular names and the player with the most unique names. The database, called "babynames", is just four columns.

```
ID | BabyFirstName | BabyMiddleName | PlayerName
---|---------------|----------------|-----------
```

My mom has changed things every so often, but as they stand right now, I have to figure out :

a) The most popular name (or names if there is a tie) out of all first and middle names

b) The most unique name (or names if there is a tie) out of all the first and middle names

c) The player that has the most number of popular names (wins a prize)

d) The player that has the most number of unique names (wins a prize)

I've been working on this for about a week now and can't even get a SQL query for a) and b) to work, much less c) and d). I'm more than just a bit frustrated.

BTW, I'm just looking at spellings of the names, not phonetics. As I manually enter names, I will change names like "Kris" to "Chris" and "Xtina" to "Christina" etc.

Editing to add a couple of the most recent queries I tried for a)

```
SELECT [BabyFirstName], 
       COUNT ([BabyFirstName]) AS 'FirstNameOccurrence' 
FROM [babynames] 
GROUP BY [BabyFirstName] 
ORDER BY 'FirstNameOccurrence' DESC 
LIMIT 1
```

and

```
SELECT [BabyFirstName] 
FROM [babynames] 
GROUP BY [BabyFirstName] 
HAVING COUNT(*) = 
    (SELECT COUNT(*) 
     FROM [babynames] 
     GROUP BY [BabyFirstName] 
     ORDER BY COUNT(*) DESC 
     LIMIT 1)
```

These both lead to syntax errors.

```
pyodbc.ProgrammingError: ('42000', '[42000] [Microsoft][ODBC Microsoft Access Driver] Syntax error in ORDER BY clause. (-3508) (SQLExecDirectW)')
```

I've tried using [FirstNameOccurrence] and just FirstNameOccurrence as well with the same error. Not sure why it's not recognizing it by that column name to order by.

```
pyodbc.ProgrammingError: ('42000', "[42000] [Microsoft][ODBC Microsoft Access Driver] Syntax error. in query expression 'COUNT(*) = (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM [babynames] GROUP BY [BabyFirstName] ORDER BY COUNT(*) DESC LIMIT 1)'. (-3100) (SQLExecDirectW)")
```

I'll admit that I'm not really grokking all of the COUNT(*) commands here, but this was a solution for a similar issue here in stackoverflow that I figured I'd try when my other idea didn't pan out.

Comment: You should include code you've tried that didn't work (IE your SQL query for A and B that isn't working) and ask for pointers on how to fix what you have. As it stands, it sounds like you're asking us to write your code for you and that isn't the purpose of SO.

Answer (score 0):

For A and B, use a `group by` clause in your SQL, and then count, and `order by` the count. Use descending order for A and ascending order for B, and just take the first result for each.

For C and D, essentially use the same strategy but now just add the PlayerName (e.g. `group by babyname,playername`) and then use the ascending order/descending order question.

Here's Microsoft's write-up for a `group by` clause in MS Access: https://office.microsoft.com/en-us/access-help/group-by-clause-HA001231482.aspx

Here's an even better write-up demonstrating how to do both `group by` and `order by` at the same time: http://rogersaccessblog.blogspot.com/2009/06/select-queries-part-3-sorting-and.html

Answer (score 0):

For the first query you tried, change it to:

```
SELECT TOP 1 [BabyFirstName], 
       COUNT ([BabyFirstName]) AS 'FirstNameOccurrence' 
FROM [babynames] 
GROUP BY [BabyFirstName] 
ORDER BY 'FirstNameOccurrence' DESC
```

For the second, change it to:

```
SELECT [BabyFirstName] 
FROM [babynames] 
GROUP BY [BabyFirstName] 
HAVING COUNT(*) = 
    (SELECT TOP 1 COUNT(*) 
     FROM [babynames] 
     GROUP BY [BabyFirstName] 
     ORDER BY COUNT(*) DESC)
```

Limiting the number of records returned by a SQL Statement in Access is achieved by adding a `TOP` statement directly after `SELECT`, not with `ORDER BY... LIMIT`

Also, Access `TOP` statement will return all instances of the top n (or n percent) unique records, so if there are two or more identical records in the query output (before TOP), and `TOP 1` is specified, you'll see them all.